# Reducing the filter complexity for rotary encoders

Tags: filter, rotary-encoder

I am using Bourns rotary encoders, specifically the PEC11R-4215F-S0024 part.

In the [datasheets](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/PEC11R.pdf), Bourns suggest a filter circuit as follows:

[image: filter circuit]

I've used this filter in a previous PCB design, and it works quite well. No lost pulses, no double counts, etc.

The problem is that I am currently designing a PCB with 5 of these encoders, and that means that the filter circuitry is adding a heap of components to the BOM: 20 resistors and 8 capacitors in total (which I could do in array form, but arrays tend to be expensive parts.)

I have three questions:

1. How does the filter work?
2. Are there alternative filters with less complexity?
3. Can I consolidate parts if I need 5 encoders?

Comment: research `switch debouncing`

Comment: Personally, unless I was designing for tens of thousands of these in production, I would just design as recommended.  SMD resistors and capacitors are very cheap and can be had in very small packages.  If I was so tempted, I would still leave the pads in and just try not populating the caps and jumping the resistors, so I can add them later if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's just a generic RC filter. It low pass filters the noisy edges of contact bounce.
2. It can't be any simpler or you start losing features. If your MCU has pull-up resistor built-in, you might be able to rearrange and recalculate the components to come up with circuit that has two resistors less per encoder.
3. No, each wire needs 2 resistors and 1 capacitor. You could use nearby values for resistances and capacitances, but keep the RC time constants roughly the same. You really need 20 resistors and 10 caps. Or use arrays. That's the price you must pay for using electromechanical user interface components.

In a pinch you could remove all components and use built-in MCU pull-ups, and then filter the garbage in software. However, you might not want to do that if the RC filters just work and you don't want to waste time developing a debounce algorithm for noisy encoders and use precious CPU time to run the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How does the filter work?

The output resistors (pictured horizontally) work with the caps to low-pass filter the output.  I.e., the caps smooth the output voltage.

> 3. Can I consolidate parts if I need 5 encoders?

No, but it's a fine opportunity for using resistor arrays.

> 2. Are there alternative filters with less complexity?

Yes, depending on what's decoding it, and the electrical noise environment.  There's more than one scheme for decoding quadrature encoders like that -- there's at least one of them that is, in the long term, utterly insensitive to switch bounce.  There are others that fail to work correctly at all if there's switch bounce.

All will fail if there's electrical noise being injected.

If you have a robust decoder*, and a sane electrical environment, then you just need the pullup resistors (the ones shown as running up and down).  If you're implementing a robust decoder on software on a microcontroller, and that microcontroller has built-in pullup resistors, you just need to run the contacts into the microcontroller.

---

* Basically you sample the encoder pins, and track the encoder pin state with your own 4-value state.  As long as you sample fast enough to catch those times when the encoder settles out, then during switch bounce interval the worst that'll happen is that your decoded value will dither between two increments.

Answer (score 3):

It is great that you're looking to simplify things, but this is perhaps a case where "simplification" is a misnomer.

I can almost guarantee that the time spent pondering this "problem" costs more than can be saved on the parts.

We're talking about 4 components per encoder. 4 components that cost what, 1 cent each in smallish quantities?

And now imagine that you get rid of the filter or modify it - how much will it cost to validate that solution? Should there be transient glitches in the field, how much would debugging that cost?

You can find capacitor and resistor arrays, and that would reduce the number of parts, at the price of lower part availability. If you have no experience with field performance of array parts in this application, that's another potential pitfall. Let's say the array capacitors do much worse when exposed to ESD, for example.

> How does the filter work?

It's a 1st order RC lowpass.

> Are there alternative filters with less complexity?

Lower complexity than a single RC stage per line? Nope.

> Can I consolidate parts if I need 5 encoders?

Yes - array parts. The potential production slowdown due to lower availability, the potential for higher ESD susceptibility, and any unforeseen in-the-field issues will wipe out savings within the first 15 minutes of occurrence unless you're making 100s of thousands of these things. Even if something as benign as failing ESD susceptibility happens, you're already in the hole for a couple k$ if you take into account full  cost with overheads.